# PHP fopen for URL: Alternatives on Windows

Tags: php, windows, iis

I'm using the following code in PHP5 on *nix systems to call a remote URL (handover of 2 parameter to a remote system:

```
$fp = fopen($url, "r");
$contents = stream_get_contents($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Unfortunately it fails for https (http works correctly) on Windows/IIS with the following error message (although allow_url_fopen is definitely enabled):

`fopen(https://www.example.com/?method=abc&par=xyz) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No error in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\libs\externalSys.php on line 122`

Hence my **questions**:

1. Has anyone else found a solution?
2. Are there any alternatives? Curl
   is unfortunately not
   installed/available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you may not have included the php_openssl.dll in your php.ini, so https fopens will fail.  Does it work with just standard http?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

Usage:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, but the behavior is unfortunately the same: http works correctly, https gives the same error message (only with [function.file-get-contents] in the message).